# Java program for solving system of linear equations using LU decomposition

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to write a program that solves system of linear equations using LU decomposition (max matrix size of 100x100)? I am new to programming but I've been watching tutorial videos so I know some basic things in Java. I am also using Eclipse with Windows Builder. I'm having a hard time working with for loops in arrays (which I see in most java docs) so I'm asking for your help. I've already done programs for solving quadratic equations etc, this is the last one I need for my project. BTW, I'm a civil engineering student. TIA!

here's what i did in a 3x3 matrix. Im planning to do this until 100x100. -.-

```
   if(n==3) {


        double [][]l = new double[n][n];

        l[0][0] = l[1][1] = l[2][2] = 1;

        l[0][1] = l[0][2] = l[1][2] = 0;


        double [][]u = new double[n][n];

        u[1][0] = u[2][0] = u[2][1] = 0;



        u[0][0] = mat[0][0];

        u[0][1] = mat[0][1];

        u[0][2] = mat[0][2];



        l[1][0] = mat[1][0]/mat[0][0];

        u[1][1] = mat[1][1] - (l[1][0]*u[0][1]);

        u[1][2] = mat[1][2] - (l[1][0]*u[0][2]);



        l[2][0] = mat[2][0]/u[0][0];

        l[2][1] = (mat[2][1] - l[2][0]*u[0][1])/u[1][1];


        u[2][2] = mat[2][2] - (l[2][0]*u[0][2]) - (l[2][1]*u[1][2]);


        double []b = new double[n]; // for b prime
        b [0] = bs [0] ;
        b [1] = bs [1] - (l [1] [0] * b [0])    ;
        b [2] = bs [2] - (l [2][0] * b [0]) - (l [2][1] * b [1]);

        double []x = new double[n];  // for Xs
        x [2] = b[2] / u [2][2];
        x [1] = ((-u [1][2] * x [2]) + b[1]) / u [1][1];
        x [0] = (-(u [0][1] * x [1]) - (u [0][2] * x [2]) + b [0]) / u [0][0];
```

Comment: Been a while since I did any matrix math, but from memory this one is not super difficult. You will do well to include your attempt, condensed into as small a code sample as you can (i.e. not ALL the code) and show us where you're having difficulties. Are you trying to loop over a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: is there an easier way so i don't have to code for 4x4, ~100x100?

Answer (score 0):

This will be a case of trying to generalise what you can, and use loops to avoid having to hand code each line with specific indexes.

For example, this part:

```
u[0][0] = mat[0][0];
u[0][1] = mat[0][1];
u[0][2] = mat[0][2];
```

Could be refactored into:

```
for(int i = 0; i <=2; i++) {
    u[0][i] = mat[0][i];
}
```

And notice in the for loop where I say:

```
for(int i = 0; i <=2; i++)
```

The 2 is the size of the matrix (array is 0-indexed, so 2 indicates a 3x3 array with array indexes 0, 1, 2.

You'll be able to implement loops like this in a few places, and hopefully enough places that you can generalise all of the code to work for any size matrix. See how you go and post back if you get stuck.